# Golang http package: Request.WithContext method src code explanation

Tags: http, pointers, go

Following is an excerpt from source code of `http/request.go` line 290:

```
// WithContext returns a shallow copy of r with its context changed
// to ctx. The provided ctx must be non-nil.
func (r *Request) WithContext(ctx context.Context) *Request {
    if ctx == nil {
        panic("nil context")
    }
    r2 := new(Request)      //
    *r2 = *r                // strange gymnastics
    r2.ctx = ctx            //
    return r2
}
```

I looked at it for an hour trying to understand last 4 lines. Why is that gymnastics for? Doesn't it means just the following:

```
r.ctx = ctx
return r
```

Or do I miss something?

Comment: The documentation says it returns a shallow copy of the request. If it just returned `r` it wouldn't be a copy.

Comment: I know what documentations says, I try to understand what happens under the hood

Answer (score 8):

Let's examine the lines in question:

```
r2 := new(Request)
```

This is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), creates the `r2` variable, and initializes it with the value of the right-hand side expression, which is a call to the builtin [`new()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) function, which allocates memory for the given type, and returns a pointer to it (being the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the type).

```
*r2 = *r
```

This line assigns the value *pointed* by `r` to the value *pointed* by `r2`. Note that this does not assign the pointer value, but the *pointed* value. Since the pointed value is of type `Request` which is a struct, the assignment copies the values of the fields.

```
r2.ctx = ctx
```

Since `r2` is a pointer to a struct, this is a shorthand for `(*r2).ctx = ctx`, which assigns the given context value to the `ctx` field of the value (of type `Context`) pointed by `r2`.

```
return r2
```

This `r2` pointer is then returned. Note that `r2` is a pointer different from `r`, and the pointed value is a different and independent request from that pointed by `r`.

---

If you would do

```
r.ctx = ctx
return r
```

It would assign the context to the `ctx` field pointed by `r`, and this same `r` pointer would be returned. The returned value would be identical to the value of `r`, so both `r` and the returned value would point to the same `Request` value, and both would have the new `Context` value. The original code does not modify the `ctx` of the original request (the one whose `WithContext()` method is called).

Comment: I got it! The key phrase is: _Since the pointed value is of type Request which is a struct, the assignment copies the values of the fields._ Thanks!